# vee-validate parent $validator injection to child component is not working when enable automatic Injection mode

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate, vue-class-components

I'm using `vue-class-component`, `vue-property-decorator`, i want pass parent $validator to child component like this.

```
// in parent component
@Provide() $validator = '$validator';
```

```
// in child component
@Inject() $validator;
```

but, it's not working.

however, when i disable automatic Injection like this `Vue.use(VeeValidate, {inject: false});` and make new `$validator` in parent component.

```
  // in parent component
  $_veeValidate: {
    validator: 'new'
  },
```

and i just add Inject code in child component so, every works fine!

```
// in child component
@Inject() $validator;
```

I want using automatic injection.(i don't want to explicitly new to every component) why not working component injections with enable automatic injection in my case?

Thank you in advance.